# How to change the border color(un-focused) of an EditText?

Tags: android, colors, android-edittext, border

I changed the background color of the EditText to transperant. Now the EditText looks invisible when not focused. So how can I change the un-focused border color of EditText?

What is the XML attribute for this?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Create a XML file with the following in drawable (say backwithborder.xml):

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#00000000" />
    <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#ffffff" />
</shape>
```

and for the EditText user attribute `android:background="@drawable/backwithborder"`

Answer (score 11):

To set the background of edittext to transparent you can use following :

```
android:background="@null"
```

See following links

[Android EditText Transparent Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712378/android-edittext-transparent-background)

[setting the background attribute to transparent in editext dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298452/setting-the-background-attribute-to-transparent-in-editext-dynamically)

[Overriding onDraw() for an EditText widget with a blank implementation has no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945143/overriding-ondraw-for-an-edittext-widget-with-a-blank-implementation-has-no-ef)

http://www.androidworks.com/changing-the-android-edittext-ui-widget

Answer (score 7):

It's so late for answered but I wrote this code for new developers:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/components_colorPrimaryDark" />
                    <solid android:color="@color/components_white" />
                </shape>
            </item>

            <item android:bottom="2dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@color/components_white" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="false">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/components_colorAccent" />
                    <solid android:color="@color/components_white" />
                </shape>
            </item>

            <item android:bottom="1dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@color/components_white" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Great answer @jordiz, did exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 5):

Android OS itself adds border to EditText when user focus on it. The color depends on the OS version. Sometimes we might want to get rid of default focus border and there is a way to do it.

We can keep the background color as transparent to remove the EditText border on focus.

```
     <EditText 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="#00000000"
      />
```

Comment: The question is about the unfocused state, not the focused one.

Answer (score 5):

You can use attr `app:backgroundTint` if you only want to change the EditText border color:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:backgroundTint="#000"
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a linearlayout with background color the color which you want the border should be. Then place the Edit text inside this `Linearlayout` and give some background color. 
Eg : if border is grey then background for `Linearview` is grey.
and edit text background black.

for width of border you can give `padding = "1dp"` for `border_width = "1dp"`.