# How to draw EditText with horizontal lines?

Tags: android, android-edittext

As I want to Create a Notepad and I want Edit Text with horizontal lines. Please let me know from where I need to start? I have create Edit text with simple xml layout, I also have viewed some examples but unable to understand the concept of it. Please let me how to draw edit text with horizontal lines?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to have an `EditText` with border lines,like a footer and a header?If so,it is possible duplicate : [How to change the border color(un-focused) of an EditText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224560/how-to-change-the-border-colorun-focused-of-an-edittext)

Comment: hi, no I want horizontal lines in Edit Text for Text.

Comment: Draw it maybe...cause it is not clear how exactly you want this "lines" to be.

Comment: Like in a notepad When we click on "Create Note", We can see EditText Section, like a piece of paper, lines draw on it and We can write our text on it.

Comment: I am sorry I don't know about which notepad you are talking.

Answer (score -1):

There's an Android notepad tutorial: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html

It would be a good place to start.

If you are trying to load the notepad text, then you'll need to do that in code. Something like

```
         <EditText
     android:id="@+id/editor"
      .../>
```

Then in code,

```
    String savedText = loadTextFromFile();
    EditText editor = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editor);
    editor.setText(savedText);
```

Then you just need to write the loadTextFromFile() method to actually get the notepad text. This is the same as you would do it in Java.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @Simon, Did you get what she is asking for?

Comment: @nOiAd  A notepad looking like a lined piece of paper.  http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-2Wm3IZxyW8A/T3oKFl1f-mI/AAAAAAAAB7I/VqLmL7fGZKA/s1600/lined-paper-no-pict1.jpg