# AutocompleteTextView with CUSTOM border color ON FOCUS

Tags: java, android, xml

to set an AutocompleteTextView border with any other color, have I to act on the resource XML or on the main java file?

This is my XML resource file:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/start_box"
    style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.AutoCompleteTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/write_text"/>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the border color(un-focused) of an EditText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224560/how-to-change-the-border-colorun-focused-of-an-edittext)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3496310/6891563 did you try this?