# when selected add border shape for textView and editText ,

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, shapes

I want to create a border shape for `TextView` and `EditText`, and show it when a `view` is **selected**.

Just like in this **picture**.

[image: example]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the border color(un-focused) of an EditText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224560/how-to-change-the-border-colorun-focused-of-an-edittext)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/23417544/7319704

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use drawable selector to achieve your UI.

First create a `background_edit_text_default.xml` which is the background of EditText when it is not selected by users.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#333D46" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="10dp"
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:top="10dp" />
</shape>
```

Then create a `background_edit_text_selected.xml` which is the background of EditText when it is selected by users.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#EDB90E" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="10dp"
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:top="10dp" />
</shape>
```

Next create a `background_edit_text.xml` which will be used as background of the EditText.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_edit_text_default" android:state_focused="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_edit_text_selected" android:state_focused="true" />

</selector>
```

Finally set `background_edit_text.xml` as background of your EditText in your layout file, such as `activity_main`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/conteiner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background_edit_text" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background_edit_text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You're done and no need to add anything in code.

Answer (score 1):

In Drawable create xml file and use this code:

```
       <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
       <corners android:radius="5dp" />
       <stroke
              android:width="3dp"
              android:color="@color/yellow" />
       </shape>
```

set it to background of EditText
after it create another one with `android:width="0dp"` and when user clicked, you can simply change them.

.....

```
editText1.setOnClickListener{
  editText1.setBackground(shape1);
  editText2.setBackground(shape0);
}
editText2.setOnClickListener{
  editText1.setBackground(shape0);
  editText2.setBackground(shape1);
```

}

you can't copy and execute this code but this is a guide for you .!

Comment: can you tell me , how to set when user clicked, you can simply change them?

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

> MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText edtEmail, edtPassword;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        edtEmail = findViewById(R.id.edtEmail);
        edtPassword = findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);

        edtEmail.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus)
                    edtEmail.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.edt_focus_bg));
                else
                    edtEmail.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.edt_unfocus_bg));
            }
        });

        edtPassword.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus)
                    edtPassword.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.edt_focus_bg));
                else
                    edtPassword.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.edt_unfocus_bg));
            }
        });


    }

}
```

> layout.activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".FirstFragment">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:text="Email"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edt_focus_bg"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Password"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edt_unfocus_bg"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edt_focus_bg"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textColor="#fae81e" />


</LinearLayout>
```

> drawable/edt_focus_bg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#fae81e" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="10dp"
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:top="10dp" />
</shape>
```

> drawable/edt_unfocus_bg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#333D46" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="10dp"
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:top="10dp" />
</shape>
```

> **OUTPUT**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvCqTc_y124

### **EDIT**

if you want to add same effect in your login `TextView` than follow below steps

- Create a `tv_text_color.xml` in `res/color` directory like

[image]

- Create a `tv_bg.xml` in `res/drawable` directory like

> Sample code for  `tv_text_color.xml`

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Focused and not pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:color="#000000" />
    <!-- Focused and pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:color="#fae81e" />

    <!-- Unfocused and pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:color="#fae81e" />

    <!-- Default color -->
    <item android:color="#000000" />
</selector>
```

> Sample code for  `tv_bg.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/edt_focus_bg" 
        android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/edt_focus_bg"
        android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/edt_unfocus_bg"/>

</selector>
```

> Now use like this in your TextView

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/tv_text_color"
    android:background="@drawable/tv_bg"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Login"
    />
```

> **OUTPUT** with `textview`

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iu898vafXEk

### EDIT 2

> You can also do the same effect for `EditText` using selector

Create a `edt_selector.xml` file in `res/drawable` directory like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/edt_focus_bg"
        android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/edt_unfocus_bg"/>

</selector>
```

> Now use in your `editext` like this

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtPassword"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edt_selector"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your color folder:

selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true" android:color="your_border_color"/>
<item android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

add this to your drawable folder:

background:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="back_ground_color" />
<corners android:radius="5dp" />
<stroke
    android:width="3dp"
    android:color="@color/selector" />
</shape>
```

to your edit text:

```
<EditText>
   android:background="@drawable/background"
</EditText>
```