# Disable EditText but receive touch/click events

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I would like to have `Recyclerview` with `EditText` views inside each row. I need to disable `EditText` for each row except the first one. I do it with

```
holder.edittext.isCursorVisible = false
holder.edittext.isClickable = false
holder.edittext.isFocusable = false
holder.edittext.isFocusableInTouchMode = false
```

However, I would like to have the `ViewGroup` of each row, for example, `Linear Layout` to be clickable in for all rows. Then I need to receive click events in `EditText` and pass it to `ViewGroup` even if the `EditText` is disabled. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: is this edittext your direct child to parent view? if yes then your code should work. if no then you will need to add this properties to intermediate parent.

Comment: Yes, it is a direct child. Nilesh's answer worked. I marked it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Disable EditText

You can use **`holder.edittext.isFocusable = false`** to disable your `EditText`

> Then I need to receive click events in `EditText` and pass it to `ViewGroup` even if the `EditText` is disabled. Is it possible to do so?

You can set `ClickListener` to your `EditText` and pass click event to your `ViewGroup` using [**`performClick()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performClick())

- **`performClick ()`**

  Call this view's OnClickListener, if it is defined. Performs all normal actions associated with clicking: reporting accessibility event, playing a sound, etc.

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    EditText myEditText;
    LinearLayout rootView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myEditText = findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
        rootView = findViewById(R.id.rootView);

        myEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                rootView.performClick();

            }
        });

        rootView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Prem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

as per your below comment *how can I disable my EditText changing colour on touch/click even when I have it focusable = false?*

follow this answer  [when selected add border shape for textView and editText ,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353887/when-selected-add-border-shape-for-textview-and-edittext/52922364#52922364)

Comment: Thanks! @Nilesh, how can I disable my EditText changing colour on touch/click even when I have it focusable = false?

Comment: @Angelina follow  this answer it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353887/when-selected-add-border-shape-for-textview-and-edittext/52922364#52922364